Grafana - datasource as variable
I have one InfluxDB database, and a lot of buckets and a lot of datasources (where one datasource = access to one bucket). As You see, schema is simple: each datasource (named influxdb-clientXXX-r) have access only to one bucket (named clientXXX) where XXX is 100, 200, 300, etc. And now, how I can use Datasource as variable? it is important for me, because I want to isolate access for buckets, so I do not provide to Grafana datasource with access to all buckets. Probably I need dashboard variables, where each variable will be converted to datasource and bucket. So if user choose variable "100", Grafana should use influxdb-client100-r as datasource, and in query, Grafana should use in query from(bucket: "client100").
I cannot do one datasource with access to all bucket, because in that case Grafana user when will be edit dashboard, can change bucket to another, but I want protect platform before this, so I create separated Datasources (where one datasource = access to one bucket).


You can't derive data source variable from other variables. But you can have data source variable, which will be selected by user, and then derive name of the bucket from data source name. Don't know how to do it in influx, but general way of how new variable can be created from value of other variable outlined here
